# On click is not refreshing the tabledata

Tags: gwt, button

Hi I have been trying to reinitiate the data in a table by using an onClick handler
But when I click the data the older data persists and along with that the new data is coming up

Kindly let me know how can I resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

```
private  void showErrorButton() {
    //super.initWidget(widget);

    _displayAlerts.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        /**
         * Click event for hiding dialog box.
         */
        public void onClick(final ClickEvent arg0) {
            getCustomDialog().getDialogBox().center();
            getCustomDialog().getDialogBox().show();
            showDialogBox(_errorList,_warnList);        
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What type of table are you using? [FlexTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html), [Grid](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html), or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not clearing the old data from your table before populating it with new data.

If you're using a [`Panel (GWT Javadoc)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html) (or any subclass of Panel such as HTMLTable, FlexTable, etc.) you should call the method [`clear()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html#clear%28%29) before adding the new data.

```
void onClick(...) {
    yourTable.clear();
    yourTable.addNewData();
}
```

I'll change my answer as I learn more about your specific problem if this doesn't help.

Comment: thanks for the idea ... I had to put a horizontalpanel inside wich this table was updated...so I cleard the panel  and now it works fine... :)